# Azure kubernetes - How to install spinnaker?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am trying to install and configure spinnaker on azure kubernetes. I don't find any documentation clearly explaining the process.

Is there any documentation available on installing and configuring spinnaker on azure kubernetes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Azure quickstart templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates) contains [spinnaker Continuous Deployment to Kubernetes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/301-jenkins-acr-spinnaker-k8s) template that

> allows you to deploy and configure a DevOps pipeline from an Azure
> Container Registry to a Kubernetes cluster. It deploys an instance of
> Jenkins on a Linux Ubuntu 14.04 LTS VM and an instance of Spinnaker on
> the same Kubernetes cluster that your pipeline will target.
>
> The Jenkins instance will include a basic pipeline that checks out a
> user-provided git repository, builds the Docker container based on the
> Dockerfile at the root of the repo, and pushes the image to the
> provisioned Azure Container Registry. The Spinnaker instance will
> include a basic pipeline that is triggered by any new tag in the
> registry and deploys the image to the provisioned Kubernetes cluster.

also check [spinnaker on azure kubernetes service](https://github.com/Jay-Wani/spinnaker-azure)